# Testing the OpenZeppelin ReentrancyGuard

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin, reentrant-attacks

I have a contract, which is using [ReentrancyGuard](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol) . Is there a way simulate reentrancy through a hardhat/mocha test? Calling a function twice without waiting for it to finish doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to the function from an attack contract which has a fallback function which again calls your victim contract.

The way to do it is:

1. Create an interface of your contract.
2. Call the contract using its interface and deployed address using your new attack contract.
3. Write a fallback function which again calls the same function.
4. You'll get the reentrancy revert strings.